# how to upload offline clicked photos ,after restarting mobile in android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am facing an issue for uploading photos in Firebase storage in a particular scenario. For example, I have clicked 10 photos in offline mode and then my mobile goes switched off when I switched on my mobile again I lost all photo path which I am using for uploading photos on Firebase, when mobile didn't switch off photo uploading working fine.

I am doing like this way https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-tutorial-android/

Comment: Hello saurabh, Currently firebase supports offline database support where you can hold the data from firebase realtime database in persistance storage. It is currently not available for firebase storage. For more https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Answer (score 1):

You will need to maintain some persistent storage (e.g. sqlite database) to store pending operations that takes longer time and depends upon many circumstances (e.g. network availability, whether activity killed etc). You can maintain some flag there for upload status that is, for example, set to "pending" when user clicked photo and changed to "done" on upload success (or can be erased) in onSuccessListener.

And each time when device starts, application starts or dependent circumstances changes back, this upload status database will need to be checked whether there is any pending work.

Using dedicated service for whole process will be reliable.

Have a look of handling firebase transactions offline and across device restarts:

[Handling Transactions Offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-handling-transactions-offline)

Comment: you right we can do this but i didn't want to use sqlite for this. i want to do it with help of firebase only like we can store text values offline and can able to sync it when come online even if the mobile get switch off and switch on again